# Rename a document in FirebaseFirestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any method to rename a document in Firebase firestore? Thanks for feedbacks. I have made several research but I cant figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that by "renaming a document in Firebase Firestore" you mean changing its ID (also known as its [name](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model#documents)). It is not possible to change the ID of a Firestore document.

You will need to copy the existing Document to a new Document to which you assign a new ID.

Comment: yes, I mean document's ID. I think about copy the existing Document but it means that i have to get all the attributes to create a new hashmap and then create new Document which seem like very roughly. Is there faster way to copy the field of the old Document? Thank you for your consideration